# Leaflet circleMarker's not working - but marker works fine

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, jquery

Using Leaflet, I'm adding around 15,000 circleMarker's to a geoJson layer. The circleMarker's, however, are not showing on my map when the layer is added, despite specifying the relevant styling options. Weirdly, the markers work correctly when I use `.marker` and a div icon, rather than `.circleMarker`. The layer is definitely being added to the map, and the circleMarker's are definitely being added to the layer.

What could be causing this issue? Heres my code:

```
function launchInteractiveMap ( attacksNodemap ) {

    const mapboxAccessToken = 'randomToken';

    map = L.map('interactive-map', { attributionControl: false } ).setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);

    var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });

    var darkStyle = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/lbamber/ck13kjh340v741cmwjsgjqop9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {tileSize: 512,zoomOffset: -1}).addTo(map);

    // circleMarkers TRYING TO BE ADDED

    var nodeLayer = L.geoJson();

    attacksNodemap.forEach(function (item, index) {

        L.circleMarker([item.latitude, item.longitude], {
            renderer: myRenderer,
            color: '#FF0000',
            radius: 10
            }).addTo(nodeLayer);

    });

    // ADDING LAYER TO MAP
    map.addLayer(nodeLayer);
    map.flyTo([39.097845, -99.050912], 3);

}

launchInteractiveMap( attacksData );
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404626/leaflet-circlemarkers-don%C2%B4t-show-up) question which indicates that a crossover of d3 css could be to blame, however after removing all the links for d3 that I was using for other charts, the issue still persists.

I am also using other geojson layers with my map, however after removing these the issue was not resolved.

Comment: It's hard to follow the logic of the code without possibility to run it. Can you describe a bit more about "until I added functionality which allows for the page and scripts used by the map to be removed and readded." Which part of the code is this? Why are you trying to remove layers when map is not initialized? When dynamically adding an removing layers, it's always good to check: remove if layer is on the map, add if layer is not on the map with `map.hasLayer` method.

Comment: @tomazicM thanks for your reply, I've done a bit more investigation and re-clarified my question.

Comment: You're calling `launchIneractiveMap()` with no parameters, so `attacksNodemap` becomes `undefined` inside the function. Other than that, [works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/ttucfxwjJV18BBMtzedc?p=preview)

Comment: @IvanSanchez apologies, I forgot to include the parameter definition - I have been passing this parameter so this is not the issue.